# dot is being taken is forward slash in gradle script

Tags: java, gradle, dsl

I am trying to below code

```
compile "release/20.02:HspJS:"
compile "${PLANNING_BRANCH_NAME_LOCATION}:EpmStructure:"
compile "${PLANNING_BRANCH_NAME_LOCATION}:EpmStructureModel:"
compile "${SM_BRANCH_NAME_LOCATION}:HSFServer:"
compile "${CALCMANAGER_BRANCH_NAME_LOCATION}:calcmgrcommon:"
```

I am getting below output

```
http://artifacthub.com/epmpbcs-release-local/release/**20/02**/HspJS.jar
```

But the desired output is

```
http://artifacthub.oraclecorp.com/epmpbcs-release-local/release/**20.02**/HspJS.jar
```

This is a gradle file. Kindly let me know what I am missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the way artifacts coordinates are translated into folders in a repository like Maven Central and others. This uses a similar translation from dotted names like is applied for Java packages.

For example, the artifact `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:<version>` is located at `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/<version>/jackson-core-<version>.jar`.

The artifact you are trying to reference seems to have a non-standard layout (or at least, not the Maven layout). I would have expected coordinates like `release:HspJS:20.02` (which would then translate to location http://artifacthub.com/epmpbcs-release-local/release/HspJS/20.02/HspJS-20.02.jar

If your repository uses a non-standard layout, then you need to configure gradle to take this into account. See [Declaring repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html)

Given the example, you will probably need to declare your repository as something like:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url "http://artifacthub.oraclecorp.com/epmpbcs-release-local"
        patternLayout {
            artifact "[module]/[revision]/[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}
```

and then declare your dependency as:

```
compile "release:HspJS:20.02"
```